# Texmaker - only show image name while inserting images

Tags: graphics

I am new with Texmaker. I am trying to insert some images in a document, but only a box with the image name shows up. I tried many compilation settings, two different extensions .png and .eps. But I cannot figure out what is wrong. Here below is the basic code structure.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}

    \includegraphics[height = 3cm]{joints.png}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! 1) What are the extensions of your graphic files? 2) Do you compime with `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: Remove the `draft` option. You can leave out the extension altogether, whatever engine you use will then choice the appropriate file type.

Comment: I removed the draft option, and it's working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment

Comment: @Moriambar I'd rather suggest that an answer is put together.

Comment: @samcarter Would you put an answer together that can be accepted? Otherwise the question remains as unanswered…

Comment: @jjdb Thanks for the ping! Found a duplicate instead.

Comment: @samcarter I've put a flag to mark it as a duplicate